# Connect to MySQL database remotely in kivy app

Tags: python, ios, mysql, xcode, kivy

Im making an app and incorporating a MySQL database into it. When I connect with my computer it works fine but when I offload the app through Xcode onto my phone I get this error message `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (61 Connection refused)`. (It works okay on the iPhone simulator on Xcode)

How do I set up my code to connect to my database remotely?

Here is the code I have for the database at the minute:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
import mysql.connector
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

def GetData():
    delete=False
    mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM words_to_add')

    myresults=mycursor.fetchall()
    word_list=[]
    for row in myresults:
        word_list=word_list+[row[0]]
    for word in word_list:
        if word in words:
            DeleteData(word)
            delete=True
    if delete ==True:
        word_list=GetData()
    return word_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alpha=Strip('Photos')
    folders= os.listdir('Videos')
    if '.DS_Store' in folders: folders.remove('.DS_Store')
    words=[]
    folders.sort()
    for folder in folders:
        globals()[folder]=Strip('Videos/'+folder)
        words=words+globals()[folder]
    words.sort()
    
    mydb= mysql.connector.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port=3306,
        user='root',
        passwd='[password]',
        database= 'nisl_data'
        )

    mycursor= mydb.cursor()
    words_to_add=GetData()
```

Comment: what's the address of the computer with the mysql server running on it?

Comment: check if u have the right permissions

Comment: You are trying to connect to mysql on the local computer ('127.0.0.1'). Unless you have a mysql server running on your phone, this will not work.

Comment: What is it I have to change?

Comment: You need to change the `connect()` command to use the ip address for the host where the `mysqld` server is running. And you probably need to configure the `mysqld` server on that host to allow remote connections.